# How to trigger commit programmaticaly on Spring Webflow 2 with Flow Managed Persistence Context

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, commit, spring-webflow

i have upgraded our application to SWF 2 and have implemented FMPC pattern. majority of our existing flow definitions doesn't have end-state, now using FMPC as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/flow-managed-persistence.html), you can trigger commit by putting commit=true to your end-state. Example of our flow:

1. get form object
2. save details to db (**we want to commit here**)
3. fetch the same object with refreshed data
4. display to view

its currently working with previous SWF and just using Open Session in View pattern. but we imlemented FMPC to avoid any LazyInitializationException. Now what's happening is steps 1-4 is happening except that changes are not committed, so in the view, we don't see any changes. it seems difficult to add end-state at the middle just to commit to DB and also this means we need to add so many end-state, so my question is **how to tell (SWF/FMPC) to commit "programmaticaly" without having to add the end-state tag**. If you know better approach, please tell also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Web Flows can have inheritance, so you can implement the end-state in your parent flow and then have it as a parent for all your flows.

Comment: Thanks Zilvinas, but the commit operation (read/write) can be triggered anywhere and the existing flow definition is very big that it can be dangerous or laborious to update it. Plus, i noticed that commit is triggered only when i log off from the application, thus is considered the end of the flow. I found this site very very interesting:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-springwebflow/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. I finally found out that indeed Hibernate is auto-committing all my read-write operations. The problem is when refreshing the object concerned which gave me the impression that there is no read-write done while in fact there is. Doing **sessioFactory.refresh(object)** instead of plain **find()** effectively fetched the updated data from the DB. I guess its because the hibernate session is still alive (due to FMPC) that's why doing "find" will retrieve from the hibernate cache while "refresh" means re-reading the data directly from underlying database. Please correct my analysis as necessary.